# Why do entries start at number 10?

Tags: cognito-forms

When looking at my form homepage, it says next to one of my forms that there are 41 total entries. When I look at the entries page, they are numbered from `10` to `52`.

Why isn't it `1` to `41`?

Comment: You could always create a post at the Cognito Forms [Support Forum](https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/).

Answer (score 1):

Entry numbers for new forms always start at 1.  If you create and entry and then delete it, the entry number is considered used and will never be available again.